# Need help creating local user accounts on 6 remote computers in a Windows workgroup

Tags: windows, powershell, user-accounts, workgroup

I am trying to create a simple script that prompts a local admin user to create a local user account on 6 remote computers in a Windows Workgroup. The script should prompt for the name of the user, password, and the group to which it will be a member of, and repeats the execution of the commands in all 6 computers while the script initiated only once. All 6 computers have the admin account with the same username/password.

I know the PS commands that can be used are - `New-LocalUser`, `Add-LocalGroupMember` and `PSSession`, but I just can’t make it automated enough to run with the minimal input by a local admin.

---

I tried the following script and saved it on PC01 to run from Powershell. However it gives an error that account already exists whenever it tries to create the account on PC02 and PC03 after it successfully creates the account on PC01. Also it does not Read host when remoting in to PCs.

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName PC01
New-localUser
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Users
Exit-PSSession
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName PC02
New-localUser
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Users
Exit-PSSession
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName PC03
New-localUser
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Users
Exit-PSSession
```

Comment: Something basic to start with: where's your script? Can you share it with us? Next, define "automated enough" as clearly as you are able. Where in the script is it failing, for instance. Use the EDIT button to add this helpful and necessary info to your question.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not creating a Windows image which contains these user accounts and then deploy the Windows image?

Comment: Try something like: `invoke-command -computername pc01,pc02,pc03 -scriptblock {New-localUser abc; Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Users}`. I've not had much success running `enter-pssession` in scripts that are fully automated, it's more for a  phased approach with manual interaction being required between the sessions.